# Acknowledge network parameter in Network map service

Tags: corda

I'm developing a network map service, it has rest end-points as mentioned in the Corda network map(https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html). What is the need of POST '/network-map/ack-parameters'?
What should be the test file for testing this rest end-point?

Answer (score 1):

When there is a change to the network-parameters of the network (for example, `maxMessageSize` or adding a new notary), the network of Corda nodes will need to accept the new network-parameters in order to continue transacting.  There is an `updateDeadline` which sets the deadline time when nodes must accept these new network-parameters by, before the new network-parameters are essentially enforced.

The endpoint `/network-map/ack-parameters` provides a way to accept the new network-parameters.  The payload would be the hash of the new network-parameters, which can be retrieved in 2 ways: either from the network operator OR from the Corda node crash shell, using the command `run networkParametersFeed`.

To note, this endpoint is the equivalent of using the Corda node crash shell command (with example hash):

```
run acceptNewNetworkParameters parametersHash: "ba19fc1b9e9c1c7cbea712efda5f78b53ae4e5d124c89d02c9da44ec50e9c17d"
```

More information on flag days can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#manual-acceptance